# Input CLK Keeps Showing As Hi-Z on ModelSim

Tags: fpga, verilog, quartus, modelsim

I am writing some basic verilog code that blinks an LED at some frequency. The code for the design file is the following:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns


module FPGA_Testing(input reset, input clk, output reg LED);

    reg [32:0] counter;
    reg state;


    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if(reset == 1) begin
            counter <= 0;
            state <= 0;
        end
        else begin  
            counter <= counter + 1;
            state <= counter[20];
        end

    end

    always @* begin
     LED =  state;
    end


endmodule
```

and the test module is here:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns


module FPGA_Testing_tb;

     reg clk;
     wire LED;
     reg reset;

     FPGA_Testing test(
                      reset, 
                      clk, 
                      LED
                      );


    initial     
    begin
        clk = 0;
        reset = 1;
        #10
        reset = 0;
    end

    always
    begin
        #5 clk = !clk;
    end


endmodule
```

When I compile the code, I get these as my warnings and critical warnings:

```
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (292013): Feature LogicLock is only available with a valid subscription license. You can purchase a software subscription to gain full access to this feature.
Warning (15714): Some pins have incomplete I/O assignments. Refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings report for details
Critical Warning (169085): No exact pin location assignment(s) for 3 pins of 3 total pins. For the list of pins please refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings table in the fitter report.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
    Info (11105): For recommendations on closing timing, run Report Timing Closure Recommendations in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
    Info (11105): For recommendations on closing timing, run Report Timing Closure Recommendations in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
    Info (11105): For recommendations on closing timing, run Report Timing Closure Recommendations in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning: Warning: File FPGA_Testing_run_msim_rtl_verilog.do already exists - backing up current file as FPGA_Testing_run_msim_rtl_verilog.do.bak11
Warning: Warning: File FPGA_Testing_run_msim_gate_verilog.do already exists - backing up current file as FPGA_Testing_run_msim_gate_verilog.do.bak11
```

And then when I run a RTL simulation with ModelSim, I get this

[image]

As you can see, the clk and reset values in the testbench file are correct, but the clk and reset values in the design module are both Hi-Z(which I suspect is the reason why I get undefined behavior from the other values in my design module). I am pretty sure I did the connections correctly, so I am unsure as to why I get these Hi-Z values.

Answer (score 1):

At the top-level of your simulation you have two modules:

1. FPGA_testing
2. FPGA_testing_tb

Thus somehow you managed to include your bare, unconnected "FPGA_Testing" module at the top level (alongside your test bench).

In the hierarchy I can see your module because under "FPGA_testing_tb" there is a `[+]` with the name 'test'. That is where you DUT (Device Under Test) is.

To see your module working look at the signals inside that. You should,hopefully, see your counter working in there.